# Bluemix AppID Authentication

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs, ibm-appid

I am using [Bluemix App ID](https://github.com/ibm-cloud-security/appid-clientsdk-android). I am facing Problem with authentication Problem. It works fine when my device have chrome browser. Device without chrome browser cause Authorization Failure. Exception message is:

> ```
> Could NOT find installed browser that support Chrome tabs on the device.
> ```

**Is Bluemix App ID works with chrome only?**

**Edit:**

I have checked Bluemix library class `AuthorizationUIManager` and found out that they have used [CustomTabsService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/customtabs/CustomTabsService.html) for detecting device can support Custom Tab or not.

**Can anyone explain why they need custom tab support and how to resolve the problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluemix App ID works with devices that have Chrome browser or any other browser that support Chrome tabs.

Google announced that: "authorization requests in embedded browsers will be blocked on April 20, 2017".

Since Bluemix App ID uses Google as identity provider, Bluemix App ID must use Chrome browser or one that support Chrome tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this Google announcement: 
https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html

"In the coming months, we will no longer allow OAuth requests to Google in embedded browsers known as “web-views”, such as the WebView UI element on Android and UIWebView/WKWebView on iOS, and equivalents on Windows and OS X."

Therefore the only allowed method for OAuth web flow is using Chrome Tabs.